# Remover sombra do estado :focus de um botão do Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Como eu tiro aquela animação que deixa as bordas azuis do botão quando mantenho o mouse pressionado nele, quando eu dou um click nele, ele fica com bordas azuis. Estou utilizando o Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 5):

Tem que tirar o `box-shadow` da pseudo `:focus`. Só que ai o usuário vai ficar sem um feedback visual de que clicou no botão, isso não é recomendado do ponto de vista da acessibilidade

```css
 
.btn:focus,
.btn-primary:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<form>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Faça da seguinte maneira:

```css
.btn:focus{
  box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```